# Drawing line that connects pins in ArcGIS Online Story Map?

Tags: arcgis-online, story-map

I need to draw a line in the streets connecting the pins. I have a public account.

Does any one know how to do it?

Attached is what I'm trying to accomplish.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this by accessing the web map that is being displayed by your story map app.

Once you have the web map open you could try adding a map note to it using a line template.

I did this on the sixth section (not counting the Home Section) of the Story Map Journal entitled [William & James Slight - Map Engravers & Test Cricketer](https://www.arcgis.com/apps/MapJournal/index.html?appid=163b6d4177354fbb93ba9ed4aedd8ee3)